# Where does PHP define the empty function in the PHP source code?

Tags: php, c

I'm looking through the PHP source code found [on their GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src) and I just can't seem to figure out where it is that they define the empty function. Now, this is leading me to believe that they're passing this through to C's internal functions, but I don't know enough about the design yet to be sure.

I'm curious to find out where the empty function is defined in the PHP source code.

Comment: empty is not a function, it's a language construct. A search on github for `empty` gave me [this commit](https://github.com/nikic/php-src/commit/ec061a93c53c8cde10237741e98e992c1a05d148) that includes the definition and a hint on `zend_do_isset_or_isempty`.

Comment: Well, now that's led me to a second question: How is empty a language construct, if it requires parentheses?

Comment: By definition. PHP has *lots* of inconsistencies. [Someone even compiled a list](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) a few years ago..

Comment: @TravisWeston **Why couldn't it be** a built-in language construct? What is and is not built into the language doesn't depend on the syntax of the construct itself. It only ever depends on the designer of the language. Everything else is arbitrary. E. g., in C, the `sizeof` operator requires parentheses if its argument is a type. Yet `sizeof` is not a function but a built-in operator.